# Difference of class objects and pointers

Tags: c++, class, object, pointers

Say we have this class:

```
class book {
  public:
  book(int pages = 0) {pages = m_pages;}
  getPages() { return m_pages;}
  setPages(int pages) { pages = m_pages;}
  private:
  int m_pages;
};
```

I never understand when to use a pointer to a class, or when to make an object of it. Example: what is better and why?

```
book The_lord_of_the_rings;
```

or:

```
book* The_lord_of_the_rings;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Never make a pointer.

Comment: `book(int pages = 0) {pages = m_pages;}` shouldn't it be `book(int pages = 0) {m_pages = pages;}`?

Comment: Well, one gives you an object, the other gives you a pointer to nowhere. These are completely different concepts.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for that flaw, it should be reversed.

Comment: @H2CO3: If there's a strong reason to use a raw pointer, you would know it. If you aren't sure, then you probably don't need it :-) It's only approximate advice, but I'm test-driving it to see if it makes a good first lesson.

Comment: @KerrekSB I see. :) Well, what if dynamic allocation of objects is needed? I ain't no C++ expert, but how would you implement, for example, a tree data structure with all auto objects?

Comment: @H2CO3: unique pointers and reference wrappers :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB I agree, although the "never" formulation sounds a bit absolutist. If you don't know, then it is extremely unlikely that you need a pointer.

Comment: @H2CO3: But seriously, implementing your own data structure falls under "know what you're doing". I've come to amend the general rule to read, "never use *public* naked pointers". For private variables they're OK, because they're tightly controlled by the class author and there's no semantic leak.

Comment: @KerrekSB I stand corrected. So basically, `vector<Node &> children` does the job, is that what you're saying?

Comment: @H2CO3: No, just `vector<node>`. That's already a dynamic container.

Comment: @KerrekSB I see, but wouldn't that copy every single child?

Comment: i prefer use pointer when have something to do with inheritance and virtual function. it is also useful to get rid of copy constructor called when pass as parameter to function. else use object.

Comment: @H2CO3: It was just an example... why would you copy anything, though? In a tree children belong to a unique node. At best they need to be *moved* around. (But I probably wouldn't use a vector in that place anyway. See above; *private* naked pointers are acceptable and sometimes quite appropriate for the implementation of a data structure, where all the invariants are under your control.)

Comment: @KerrekSB OK, I guess I'm just going to try it and log the copy constructors :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case the variable `The_lord_of_the_rings` *is* the object. In the second case, the variable points to somewhere else in memory where the object is.

Lets try a simple ASCII imagery:

In the first case you have an object:

```
+---------------------------------------+
| The_lord_of_the_rings                 |
| (All data associated with the object) |
+---------------------------------------+
```

In the second example you have a pointer:

```
+-----------------------+       +--------------------------------+
| The_lord_of_the_rings | ----> | The actual object and its data |
+-----------------------+       +--------------------------------+
```

**However:** As noted by juanchopanza in a comment, a pointer doesn't actually *have* to point to a valid object. If you just declare a pointer as a local variable, it's not initialized and points to a seemingly random location in memory. Dereferencing (accessing data the pointer points to) in this case leads to *undefined behavior*, and may actually crash the program. A pointer should always be initialized to point to a valid object before it can be used.

---

In modern C++ there are few reasons to use pointers, especially raw pointers. Now there are good "smart pointers" like [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) and [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).

When to use pointers depends much on the situation, but generally you can come a long way with plain objects and references.

Comment: No, in the second case, the variable just points to somewhere. Not necessarily to a location where there is an object. It doesn't have to, unlike say a reference. I think this distinction is important.

Answer (score 0):

To use Polymorphism you need to use pointer to a class.

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/

Another scenario is in embedded systems programming or whenever there is constraint on the available memory, we prefer using pointers, allocate memory on need and de-allocate memory once we are done with the use so that others can get memory when in need.

Comment: You don't really need pointers, at least not raw pointers, for polymorphism to work. The two concepts are decoupled.

Comment: Run time polymorphism to be specific

Answer (score 0):

I prefer use pointer when have something to do with inheritance and virtual function. It is also useful to get rid of copy constructor called when pass as parameter to function.  Pointers give you freedom to allocate/delete(by new/delete keyword) as you feel necessary. 
On other hand use of object will help you to reduce memory leak problem as the system will claim memory on its own when object is out of scope.